# Blueprism: how to adjust attributes so same elements are highlighted on different screen size?

Tags: spy, blueprism, rpa

I spied my elements using my laptop. Then I highlight the element I identified to make sure it is unique. This works fine when the browser window I am spying is on my laptop screen. When I move this browser window to a monitor screen, Application modeler is no longer able to identify the element I spied (it highlights a different region in the browser). I am using Browser-based applicatio -> browser launched from an executable. I was only able to identify my elements using the accessibility mode. Here are some screenshots of what happens when I highlight the element "English" from the application modeler: 
[image: Laptop Screen] [image: Monitor screen]
 What I see on my laptop screen vs what I see on the monitor.

Comment: It would be very nice to know how you spy this element?

Comment: I was using HTML mode. The solution that worked for me was to change my zoom to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I used a built-in zoom function of internet explorer.

Below you can see a printscreen of a place where you can check the zoom function in internet explorer:

[image: here]

Please check if that fixed your issue.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Changing the zoom function on my laptop and/or when viewed on my monitor didn't change the way application modeler was highlighting my element.

Comment: For those wondering, I was able to circumvent this issue by going into application modeler, clicked on dropdown image on identify button, selected  "Open Application Navigator". This allowed me to select the specifi HTML path (so something like HTML\BODY\div....)

Answer (score 0):

It would be very nice to know how you spy this element and what Attributes are clicked on/off? But here is my solution to your problem without knowing much about your data.

Open up AplicationModeller where you spy this element and find your element in the list.

I guess your page is responsive so this element is not static. In attributes there should be a name called 'Path', this refers to the HTML path at which location you will find the element. There is also an attribute called 'X' and 'Y', this is the static location of where to find your box. I would click off both 'Path', 'X' and 'Y' then I would try to click on 'Title' and see if this is enough to do the trick, 'Title' = "English".